# Passing Rails 5 Form Value to Controller as Paramerter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having trouble passing a non-model form field from view to controller. The value I am trying to pass is `amount`

Thank you.

**views/donations/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag donations_path, style: (current_user.card_last4? ? "display:none" : nil)  do %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <% if flash[:error].present? %>
          <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <article>
      <%= label_tag(:amount, 'Donation Amount:') %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:amount) %>
    </article>
    <%= link_to 'Donate', new_donation_path(amount: :amount), class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'donateButton' %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/donations_controller.erb**

```
def create
    customer = current_user.stripe_customer
    amount = params[:amount]
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    begin
      Charge.charge(amount, token)
    end
...
```

**models/charge.rb**

```
def self.charge(amount, token)
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
     amount: amount,
     source: token,
     currency: 'usd',
     description: 'Test Charge'
  )
end
    ...
```

Comment: Why doesn't what you have work? What error do you get? What are the parameters in the console log? Does your route method (POST/PATCH) match your controller method and view form action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view tag like

```
<%= text_field_tag 'donation[amount]' %>
```

And permit the parameter in your controller

```
def donation_params
  params.require(:donation).permit(:amount)
```

You can access the value with `donation_params[:amount]`.

Comment: I now get this `param is missing or the value is empty: donation` I added `amount = donation_params[:amount]` in my `create block` which is listed after my `donation_params` block.  This is my url, as you can see, the amount isn't being passed through `http://127.0.0.1:3000/donations/new?amount=amount`

Comment: I see your form submission is a direct GET link, when it should be a POST link. You should use a `<input type="submit">` button or `submit_tag` instead. The `#create` method expects the POST action.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `link_to` to trigger the form submission. Use `submit_tag` instead. Besides that, make sure your strong params whitelist whatever you're submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using strong params. Why not just add |f| at the end like this

`<%= form_tag donations_path, style: (current_user.card_last4? ? "display:none" : nil)  do |f| %>`

and then use `<%= f.text_field :amount %>`

Then at the params you should do something like `params["donation"]["amount"]` to get the value

EDIT: at the end change `link_to` for `f.submit`